# How to access to functions in other class on Kotlin?

Tags: android, function, class, kotlin

well I'm developing an app on Kotlin, so I have a class called `CreateNoteActivity.kt` in where I have a function that want to move to `ImageProcessor.kt` to make the code cleaner. Its works with 2 functions (`getResizedBitmap` and `getImageUriAndCompress`) but when I try to access to the fun `getRealPathFromURI` I have a problem cause it says :

> "Unresolved Reference: contentResolver". Note: It works if the fun
>   getRealPathFromURI is on CreateNoteActivity.kt.

Thanks as always!

**ImageProcessor.kt:**

```
package com.example.miciudadstable

import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.net.Uri
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream


class ImageProcessor {

    fun getRealPathFromURI(uri: Uri): String? {
        val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)

        cursor?.moveToFirst()

        val idx = cursor!!.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)
        val realPath = cursor.getString(idx)

        intent.putExtra("Real image path", realPath)

        Log.d("@JSCRUI getRealPathFromURI", realPath)

        return realPath
    }


    fun getResizedBitmap(image: Bitmap, maxSize: Int): Bitmap? {
        var width = image.width
        var height = image.height
        val bitmapRatio = width.toFloat() / height.toFloat()
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize
            height = (width / bitmapRatio).toInt()
        } else {
            height = maxSize
            width = (height * bitmapRatio).toInt()
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true)
    }
    fun getImageUriAndCompress(inContext: Context, inImage: Bitmap): Uri? {
        val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bytes)
        val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
            inContext.getContentResolver(),
            inImage,
            "Compressed",
            "Image created by Rawson Ciudad"
        )
        Log.d("@JSCRUI getImageUriAndCompress", path)
        return Uri.parse(path)
    }
}
```

**CreateNoteActivity:**

```
package com.example.miciudadstable

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.database.Cursor
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.StrictMode
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.tiper.MaterialSpinner
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_createnote.*
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaTypeOrNull
import okhttp3.MultipartBody
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.asRequestBody
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File


class CreateNoteActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_createnote)    
    }

    //select a picture...
    fun fromGallery(){
        val pickPhoto = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1)
    }
    fun fromCamera(){
        val takePicture = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0)
    }

    //Result from Gallery/Camera depends on choosed option.
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when(requestCode){
            0 -> if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    val selectedImageUri = data?.data
                        if (selectedImageUri != null) {

                }
            }
            1 -> if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    val selectedImageUri = data?.data
                        if (selectedImageUri != null) {

                        val imageStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(selectedImageUri)
                        val selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream)
                        val bitmapResizedImage = ImageProcessor().getResizedBitmap(selectedImage, 1024)

                    var imageUri = ImageProcessor().getImageUriAndCompress(this, bitmapResizedImage!!)
                                         ImageProcessor().getRealPathFromURI(imageUri!!)

                    let {
                        iv_pickedImage.setImageBitmap(selectedImage)
                    }

                }
            }
            else -> Log.d("@JSCRUI result: ", "No image received")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `contentResolver` seems to be a property of Activity, obtained by `getContentResolver()` on activity.

Comment: Did my answer useful?

Comment: Hi, Animesh probably you are right... Now Im thinking how to obtain on CreateNoteActivity and pass it to ImageProcessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getContentResolver()` is method of class `android.content.Context` so for use it you need to an `Activity`.

You should create your cursor in your `activity` and pass it to `ImageProcessor`  class like this :

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(imageUri!!, null, null, null, null)

ImageProcessor().getRealPathFromURI(cursor)


}
```

And change `getRealPathFromURI` fun in `ImageProcessor` to this :

```
fun getRealPathFromURI(cursor:Cursor): String? {
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Hi, Milad 
I tried the changes you suggested but how do I should create the Cursor to pass it to ImageProcessor?

Comment: I update it check it again. @JuandeSnaiderCruickshank

Comment: @JuandeSnaiderCruickshank , Did you check it?

Comment: Milad! Thank you, now it works fine, sorry for the late response. :D